# Storing values in a List, tuple and sets

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

ask you user 4 inputs. Then, these must be stored in a list, tuple and, set. If an input is invalid, the program will say which of the 3 (list, tuple, or set) cannot support what the user inputted and end the program. If successful, the program will print the data that was stored. This is the best i can do:

```
num_elements = []
tpl = ()
st = set()

list_length = int(input('Enter the range of the list: '))

try:
    for i in range(list_length):
    item = int(input('Enter the numbers: '))
    var = tpl + (tuple(item))
    num_elements.append(item)
    st.add(item)


print(str(num_elements))
print(tpl)
print(st)

except ValueError:
   print('Please enter a valid key')
```

Comment: The `except` block must be immediately after the `try` block, before the `print` statements.  You don't need `str` around `num_elements`.

Comment: This also reads like a class assignment that you're stuck on. I recommend checking out the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed some issues with your code - your try/except syntax was wrong and your tuple initialization needed some change. Let me know if this works for your purposes.

```
num_elements = []
tpl = ()
st = set()

list_length = int(input('Enter the range of the list: '))

try:
    for i in range(list_length):
        item = int(input('Enter the numbers: '))
        tpl = tpl + (item,)
        num_elements.append(item)
        st.add(item)
except ValueError:
   print('Please enter a valid key')

print(num_elements)
print(tpl)
print(st)
```